# Webrtc ICE candidate exchange between peer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have few doubt about webrtc peer to peer implementation.

1. Is it necessary to exchange ice candidate between peer.

When I check sample code I found that

```
// send any ice candidates to the other peer
pc.onicecandidate = ({candidate}) => signaling.send({candidate});

........................
........................
signaling.onmessage =...........
......................
if (candidate) {
  await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
```

2. Does the onicecandidate triggered on both peer or in offer peer only ?

I tested  that without exchanging icecandidate the video stream works.

Does it create any problem in certain condition.

Answer (score 1):

ICE Candidate will help to find the shortest path to the peer. Also onIceCandidate will trigger on both peer.

Note: I tried without sending candidate to other peer that is not works for me.